# How can I make a continuity check for a model rocket igniter?

Tags: mosfet, continuity

I am currently working on a model rocket controller. It should fire a rocket model using a standard model rocket igniter (e-match). To ensure safety, I want to check for continuity trough the igniter. My e-match will ignite at a current of 1A. To safely check continuity, the test current should not be higher than 40mA. For that purpose, I designed this small circuit:

[image: schematic]

My entire system is powered by a 2S lipo battery (7.4V-8.4V) that can deliver enough current for the ignition. My microcontroller is a ESP32-S3-WROOM. To ensure that the voltage for the continuity check stays below 3.3V, I use a voltage divider that will limit the max voltage to 2.837V. I know that in this configuration, there will be a constant current draw of around 1mA, but my rocket will only be on the launch pad a short amount of time so that isn't a big problem.

Are there any problems with that schematic? Please keep in mind that I am still a newbie so I will try my best to understand your explanation, but won't be as fast with that.

Comment: The schematic is incomplete. It is assumed that "continuity pin" is measured with respect to "GND". Ground current paths back to the battery are ambiguous.

Comment: Okay, I am not entirely sure what you mean by that, but would reversing the GND before the 10k Resistor and the +VBAT after the voltage divider solve the issue?

Comment: Yo don't need the extra voltage divider, just split the 10 kohm resistor between igniter and GND.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That circuit will not work. One simplification you can make when trying to understand circuits is to assume that power supply rails are fixed voltages. That's reasonable in your case. Notice that the voltage at these nodes are fixed:

[image: circuit with arrows to nodes]

If the voltage is fixed, it doesn't matter what else is connected there. The igniter and the 10k both see VBAT. They can't effect each other. It's like 2 people pulling on a sign post. They pull one way, you pull on another, but you have no effect on each other because the post is "fixed".

Luckily, you can easily fix this circuit by moving your voltage divider to the low side.

[image: fixed circuit]

And of course we should check the current through the igniter. 8.4/15.1E3 = 0.56mA. That should be fine.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a circuit that senses continuity and has some extra safety features ([simulate it here](https://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgjCAMB0l3BWcMBMcUHYMGZIA4UA2ATmIxAUgpABZsKBTAWjDACgAzEFGq7QvNzyD%20IlOGhIwCNthogANgwAmTAOYAnBgwB24EMWjYUzVlAqwUYYYTBWMNYghriq7MIXHP5KBIQo08rg%20iirqWrrmEFQwkOwatDSCHhR24P58bADuQoKY4ijCINgIrmwJKDy0cNxVgYJu8JBsaiCEvLR4VO1UjhlQbAAeif4sVAhg9Ezk8tYgAKJMALIAhgAuAMYAFrIY3R12gn5uhfoxbADO6dwY4u03rvprGgCuDGwAStf5ICz%20PzFqtRATAZLxyIcHuAMP9buBsrUfHDKj4qs0cqJEQFUfJ0VjMTw%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-wSkebN4Bc9yvI8qFGjgBFFNVFIwBhVDAp%20dzIvkwL3No%20jQs5UoQOKdKAy6TLxDVZTovyoCmIKhs6Q7QhPNsTSNMjEAACIADEvwYer7KchECSqAk-AGDxxB6qqRAE8RlAYDgVheBQ1iYJRlDOI1YFLLE8OJetOuJNVIJy5oEkxfbiS5FsGPdZigkO9iHUkcAZDLZC1qlGpuUez1eiezrtV4V6zuimCahglKMU2tyQckoA)):

[image]

Starting from the left, the optoisolator prevents a ground loop from accidentally firing the rocket. It also makes strong FET gate drive to reduce its Rds(on): it pulls the gate up to nearly the battery voltage. This extra drive helps the FET give the max current it can for reliable firing. On the input side the fact that it's an LED that needs a few mA reduces the possibility of a false trigger.

The 'Fire' LED will light at the same time the big FET is turned on. This allows testing the control before you wire it up to the E-Match, and also shows if it's safe to connect up.

The E-match loop has a 1uF bypass cap. This shunts any stray voltage as you connect up the wiring.

Here's the meat of what you asked for. The 'Voltage OK' LED is a pair of resistors (1k/10k) connected to the E-Match low side, then divides the voltage to a FET gate, which in turn lights a green LED when the gate is above threshold (1.5V for a typical logic-level FET.) With the circuit as-is, anything above 2V or so will light the LED, indicating continuity. You could adjust the divider to set some minimum acceptable battery voltage based on the FET threshold: not so accurate, but maybe good enough.

As it is your LiPo pack should have a protection circuit that will disconnect if the pack voltage gets below about 6V or so. If this happens you should get no LEDs at all.

The second part - connecting to a microcontroller. Since I like optoisolators so much I use these to isolate the signals being monitored. Again, this prevents a current loop forming with the microcontroller, and you get voltage translation for your trouble. As below ([simulate it here](https://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgjCAMB0l3BWcMBMcUHYMGZIA4UA2ATmIxAUgpABZsKBTAWjDACgAzEFGq7QvNzyD%20IlOGhIwCNthogANgwAmTAOYAnBgwB24EMWjYUzVlAqwUYYYTBWMNYghriq7MIXEIMhbgl-evrjy4kqqmtp6buYwkOwatHhuATTyHubYbADuQoKY4ijCINgIrmwJKDy0cNxVqYJu8JBsaiCEGOI0SW0dtMS%20VM0AHrQYgixUzkhM5GmCAKJMALIAhgAuAMYAFrIYVO3idoIIxIeF%20oNsvORH3L1gPneH2bUhvZUhVc05vFQfFI9-t9XsUBNxeKCGuVwOd8m03q5asDbsEQCwgpB5MD-qicWDmgA3HoFXoHEGDaq0aCIwaSF7-Lp-IqMqBsIlk4z7d69CkQmjUmJQOkABxAHT%20VXFxTQxRiL2caXOJzOUJyUs5xOllxyCvAKUVqsSySNMMNhUEtxo6VuzQ2JtuuptQqacTRsUglWIYEglEchEgJDANHI7vYOXNT1yptZOTJtzJQLYIwEBQ9IDw3m4Pto4EEABkAJYABQA9gAdADOACN1msGBoAJ6V4UrDYAa0rAAoUBWAJRJgx-bDkKz0HhURUgACSFZLCnWKkrABUNAW1Gp65WAMIFjQbACuBbW9KK2DwIWZ3WBZKtvhvV5eohNEZZ196t81GuBUv%20Ca%209LqGo8TNOouhBV95UBKo-yxF4b3SQJaHSZouFKERzwBIIMOMCQpBkBJEKfQjMXMNBgUQ35MKQgZIN8f5EJQfwY3tc4PxtAdgwgIhyH8EkJxhEAAHIADU5zWFYN0rAB5ABpQTKzzeYABFoXqajaDAkpEW9eBVM00oNLyHlkDgF4WUtMCHhon4wLhNSrOYtSPwo5CzP0rw7GKAzyM8rSKF8jCfPEM95DQ4pAoHYwCjBYcjIgScACIADFdwYBKFOUsygMAv4mOaDxOiApjKNxEBlAYDgVn3BQ1iYMILhiWAwxBBlstgnInxZe9LgSEqwRKki-lM65o0dR5HQ9GQRvje5HjjSboXox5UUQxpTIqSUSNRPYsRM7Eql1DADN1fb5DJI7xDJb9jtSMUDL867goMvB0gel4XqCZ70kTHIPpBH9-x%20GpOpqVassmZaSLBjqSJ2%20EqDh68IThwgISfJG%20DBQj8RaNF0hwXx0TuxEUDYAAlcwTv8mlKWwIxBRgGQljRMDEKYbpVu4OlmaYMC4fZhHBq5mQckmW6HVu4EuRVTVkXOFH5ER8nzCu%20HBTR%20mKUZ1TBH9Bo2nwcwdNMn5dcN1GDcNC29fhKikaoh1HntgnbaV02xX4V3PeaXrBBdhHvb2qXLbxu9DeDl2if9l5eb9kiLbd222dZp3caJm306%20bg09ekiia-bO1RuxWDKugcWBQYgKG6JhiEmPB6ESlLVx0NQEvLoN6D2QmnDFSAq8S0SaoktKO7PO56AmP5HknFc1w3DQ4IRFmjLKPMV8jAXIwpSqFArBhik1tgq1Dv4ISYQgu--EYWAQLiqlrkdMBzKoli3ABVTgtXC%20QnxC6VcLgBFpCaomNBAQSBmAkB6N6RozBOOUBzEEElRlJRYEGoUF8AikAA)):

[image]

This may seem complicated, but we’re talking about a couple of dollars in extra components to ensure your safety and prevent an expensive misfire. The LED drive FETs can be BSS138, 2N7002 or similar. The optos can be any kind with a current transfer ratio (CTR) of 1:1 or better.

What if all the stuff is in the same box? I'd still use the optos just for the voltage translation. And who knows, maybe you want to fire multiple rockets with the same ESP32, and have cables to these igniters?

Answer (score 2):

Your continuity pin connects to the center of a voltage divider that has +VBAT on both ends. Since the voltage is the same on both ends of the divider no current flows and the voltage on the continuity pin will always be +VBAT with respect to ground, unless the continuity pin is drawing some current.

I would measure the voltage between the igniter and ground, where the 10k resistor is. You can make the 10k a divider to get the voltage within the range of your ADC.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a no-frills continuity checker:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f8hOUP.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

LED stays lit while the E-fuse is closed and connected in-circuit. The LED will go out during launch and after the fuse vaporizes.

Comment: For extra safety, use a low-current LED which only needs a few mA and increase R3 accordingly.